# html syntax when you echo a value within a div

Tags: html

So I'm using this:

```
<div id="record-<?php echo $idi ?>" class="record">
 ....bunch of stuff...
</div>
```

and this works for my JS function and is returning the PHP value. Whenever I do this though my dev software (I'm using Dreamweaver) can't determine (see and thus highlight) the end of the div tag. Is this because the dev software sucks or cause my syntax sucks, or none of the above?

thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing wrong with your syntax. Dreamweaver should recognize a php block (if the file extension is .php). Also try to check preferences for php code highlighting options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax is fine. it's just dw. although you could shorten your php to <?=$idi?>